# Time Series Cross Validation Warning (tidymodels, fit_resamples)

Tags: r, time-series, cross-validation, resampling, tidymodels

I am trying to use `tidymodels` to run time series cross validation and have been following the Tidy Modeling with R chapters (https://www.tmwr.org/resampling#rolling).

Any help is appreciated thank you!

When I run the following code, I get "Warning message: More than one set of outcomes were used when tuning. This should never happen. Review how the outcome is specified in your model."

The `resamples$.metrics` and `resamples$.predictions` are empty except for the first `[[1]]`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)

df <- data.frame(
  year_month   =  seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2024-03-01"), "month"),
  value  =  sample(1:100, length(seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2024-03-01"), "month")))
)

splits <- sliding_window(df, lookback = Inf, skip=23, assess_start = 1, assess_stop = 1, complete = T)

model_spec <- arima_reg() %>%
  set_engine("auto_arima")

resamples <- fit_resamples(
  object       = model_spec,
  preprocessor = recipe(value ~ year_month, splits$splits[[1]]),
  resamples    = splits,
  control      = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE)
)

collect_metrics(resamples)

resamples %>%
  select(id, .predictions) %>%
  unnest(.predictions)
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [this post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/time-series-cross-validation-warning-fit-resamples/182910) on Posit Community. :) Quoting that answer:

> I'm able to replicate the issue you're seeing with the CRAN version of tune. However, if I update my tune version to the current dev version (currently 1.1.2.9021) by running devtools::install_github("tidymodels/tune") and then restarting R, the warning about >1 outcomes goes away. That tune version will be on CRAN by the end of the month.
>
> That said, some issues remain with this approach (note the number of rows in assessment(splits$splits[[1]]) and the message in show_notes(resamples)), but I'll let you troubleshoot from there.